# Normal distribution with normally distributed variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I need to find the distribution of a normal distribution with mean=0 and a variance that is drawn from a normal distribution with a non-zero mean and variance. I have located the formula for the compound distribution when the mean is drawn from normal, but not the variance. I would be grateful for any direction or reference suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make sense for any non-degenerate normal distribution on the variance. You would get negative variances with positive probability.

Comment: A similar problem arises in Bayesian statistics: Doing inference on $\sigma, \sigma^2,$ or 'precision' $\tau = 1/\sigma^2,$ one sometimes uses an inverse gamma prior distribution, because it makes finding a posterior distribution mathematically  convenient.

Comment: @Hasse1987 I appreciate the comment. Thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: @BruceET thanks very much for the note. This helps quite a bit.